# i download opencart new modules but put into file front end?

Tags: opencart

i use the version 3.0.0.1 version. i try lot but and admin > extension > installer > warring error alert **The directory catalog/controller/common is not allowed to be written to!**

Answer (score 2):

When you are installing an extension from `admin > extensions > installer` then the OpenCart system is checking the write permission of allowed directory/folder listed on the file located in `admin\controller\marketplace\install.php` on near about line No. 124.

You need to add your missing path there. Copy the missing path and paste into the `$allowed` array **and do not forget to add a trailing slash (/) at the end of your path**. See an example of missing path `catalog/controller/common` below:

[image: adding missing path with a trailing slash]

Here I'm adding the path with a trailing slash (/)

Everytime an error path you get you need to add on that file.

Comment: Why modify core files? Terrible idea.